# How To Categorize a List

Tags: python, pandas, database

Having this list:

```
list_price = [['1800','5060','6300','6800','10800','3000','7100',]
```

how do I categorize the list to be `(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 000)`?

example:

```
2000: 1800
7000:6800, 6300
```

And count them `2000(1),7000(2)`, if possible using pandas as an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rounding to the upper thousand:

```
list_price = ['1800','5060','6300','6800','10800','3000','7100']

out = (pd.Series(list_price).astype(int)
         .sub(1).floordiv(1000)
         .add(1).mul(100)
         .value_counts()
       )
```

output:

```
700     2
200     1
600     1
1100    1
300     1
800     1
0       1
dtype: int64
```

Intermediate without `value_counts`:

```
0     200
1     600
2     700
3     700
4    1100
5     300
6     800
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Can you please tell me how to name the columns

Comment: @Артем this is a Series, so there is technically no column. Try `out.to_frame(name='count')` or `out.reset_index(name='count')` if you want to convert to DataFrame (without or with the index)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed `000` at the end of categories is `10000`. Try:

```
cut = pd.cut(list_price, bins=(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000, 6000, 7000, 10000))
pd.Series(list_price).groupby(cut).count()
```